# Automatic update data file and display?

Tags: bash, function, programming-languages

I am trying to develop a system where this application allows user to book ticket seat. I am trying to implement an automatic system(a function) where the app can choose the best seats for the user.

My current database(seats.txt) file store in this way(not sure if its a good format:

```
X000X
00000
0XXX0
```

where X means the seat is occupied, 0 means nothing.

After user login to my system, and choose the "Choose best for you", the user will be prompt to enter how many seats he/she want (I have done this part), now, if  user enter: 2, I will check from first row, see if there is any empty seats, if yes, then I assign(this is a simple way, once I get this work, I will write a better "automatic-booking" algorithm)

I try to play with sed, awk, grep.. but it just cant work (I am new to bash programming, just learning bash 3 days ago).

Anyone can help?

FYI: The seats.txt format doesn't have to be that way. It can also be, store all seats in 1 row, like: X000X0XXX00XXX

Thanks =)

Comment: This is way too similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268916/bash-programmingdisplay-data-in-matrix-format and a couple of others. Adding homework tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to get you started. This script reads in each seat from your file and displays if it's taken or empty, keeping track of the row and column number all the while.

```
#!/bin/bash

let ROW=1
let COL=1

# Read one character at a time into the variable $SEAT.
while read -n 1 SEAT; do
    # Check if $SEAT is an X, 0, or other.
    case "$SEAT" in
        # Taken.
        X)  echo "Row $ROW, col $COL is taken"
            let COL++
            ;;

        # Empty.
        0) 
            echo "Row $ROW, col $COL is EMPTY"
            let COL++
            ;;

        # Must be a new line ('\n').
        *)  let ROW++
            let COL=1
            ;;
    esac
done < seats.txt
```

Notice that we feed in `seats.txt` at the end of the script, not at the beginning. It's weird, but that's UNIX for ya. Curiously, the entire while loop behaves like one big command:

```
while read -n 1 SEAT; do {stuff}; done < seats.txt
```

The `<` at the end feeds in `seats.txt` to the loop as a whole, and specifically to the `read` command.

Comment: Agree, bash is weird. I stuck at "if" statement, where i write this: if["$A"=... just because no spacing -_-!! Hey, thanks for your solution, I think it works now(hopefully, still in "trying" stage"). I found 2 seats, I just need to learn to use sed/awk/grep to replace the text now. Thanks for the niche solution

Comment: I tried this: sed -i "/^$ROW/s/0/X/$COL" seats.txt, when it reaches the case 0. But the result is abit weird. I tried, set the original file: 00000, then the result is XX0X0. Must be something wrong with my sed

Comment: Does this need to be written in bash? To be honest this is not a very good program to write in shell script. Shell scripting is great for big bulk text manipulation like sorting and searching, but fiddling with individual characters is not really its strong suit.

Comment: Sadly, yep it needs to be done in bash. Thats why I need to learn it in a short time =( Well, by implement your code, i almost done it, give me a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what help you're asking for here. "Anyone can help?" is a very broad question.

If you're asking if you're using the right tools then yes, the text processing tools (`sed/awk/grep` et al) are ideal for this given the initial requirement that it be done in `bash` in the first place. I'd personally choose a different baseline than `bash` but, if that's what you've decided, then your tool selection is okay.

I should mention that `bash` itself can do a lot of the things you'll probably be doing with the text processing tools and without the expense of starting up external processes. But, since you're using `bash`, I'm going to assume that performance is not your *primary* concern (don't get me wrong, `bash` will probably be fast enough for your purposes).

I *would* probably stick with the multi-line data representation for two reasons. The first is that simple text searches for two seats together will be easier if you keep the rows separate from each other. Otherwise, in the 5seat-by-2row `XXXX00XXXX`, a simplistic search would consider those two `0` seats together despite the fact they're nowhere near each other:

```
XXXX0
0XXXX
```

Secondly, some people consider the row to be very important. I won't sit in the first five rows at the local cinema simply because I have to keep moving my head to see all the action.

By way of example, you can get the front-most row with two consecutive seats with (commands are split for readability):

```
pax> cat seats.txt
X000X
00000
0XXX0

pax> expr $(
     (echo '00000';cat seats.txt)
         | grep -n 00
         | tail -1
         | sed 's/:.*//'
     ) - 1
2
```

The `expr` magic and extra `echo` are to ensure you get back 0 if no seats are available. And you can get the first position in that row with:

```
pax> cat seats.txt
     | grep 00
     | tail -1
     | awk '{print index($0,"00")}'
3
```

Comment: Understood. I should be specific next time. But generally, you get my idea, and convince me to use multi0line method to store the seats. Thanks

Comment: ?? The pax is?? I am new to bash, please bear with this kind of noob questions

Comment: @progamer, apologies, that's just my prompt, like `$`. It's not part of the commands.