# Read user input and update data(txt) file?

Tags: bash

I am doing a simple restaurant sit booking system as my learning of bash script. I have this data file, store in txt file (data.txt) in this format:

```
100X00
20X0X0
3000XX
4X00XX
```

The output, when user run the program like this:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1             X         
2        X         X     
3                  X    X
4   X              X    X
```

Then, I prompt user where do you want to sit?

User will enter in comma-separated format, example: A1,B1

Once the seat is not occupied, I will update to the data.txt file. My current code:

```
echo "Please enter sit number?"
read -a usersSits
```

But then, I don't know how to proceed from this point. How to do the check and how to update? Anyone?

Comment: Don't. Use a proper db(ms) or at least a language with more powerful data structures.

Comment: Hi delnan, I want to learn the basic first. Since I am half way doing it, I want to complete this task.

Comment: @delnan: apparently this is a homework question, since there have been quite a few related questions lately. Retagging as homework.

Comment: @thkala: Why do you think ao? I did post similar questions, doing the same application, because I am stuck at the situation which I need pro-programmers like you guys to teach me. Trust me, in term of programming, stackoverflow is faster and better then G**gle(sorry if i offended G**gle fans)

Comment: @commando - I don't know if it's homework, but I can tell you why that thought comes up - it's because people don't subject themselves to doing stuff like this in bash. bash is mostly used for shell scripting, and while it can be used to do more complex stuff like what you're doing, no one does it.

Comment: @commando: because I have already seen two similar questions from two other users. See comments at your previous question.

Comment: @birryree: I just find bash is interesting. I been using windows for years, and I just switched to UNIX few days ago, thus I want to explore of it, and I found BASH. [Sigh] never mind, if you guys still think this is a homework, close this question, let me go back to old-school G**gle learning method. Just wondering, if stackoveflow only allow intermediate programmers to ask questions here? A new learner like me treat in this way.. =(

Comment: @thkala: I think in your dictionary, there is no such word called: coincidence

Comment: @commando: Three different people with pretty much the same question, all within a 24-hour period. That's one hell of a coincidence. In any case, I just retagged your question. Nobody stopped you from asking questions or downvoted one of them (yet), but you have to respect our time. In a previous comment you practically admitted coming to SO before performing an extensive Google search and reading the bash/sed/awk manual on your own.

Comment: @Mr thkal: Yes, because I think learning programming through SO is faster than Google. I have read sed/awk/grep/egrep, but its not easy to understand the logic, there are lots of short form like -e,-i,-d, very hard to familiarize/memorize those all. Through practice and code it, i could memorize faster. I respect you, because you are much intelligent than me, but please do respect me as well, just because you are guessing this is a homework, you retagged my question before asking me, and now, nobody going to answer. What should I do?

Comment: @commando: generally people do answer homework questions, although they rarely just give out the solution and they are more willing to answer to people who have done their reading. As for your question, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262708/bash-automatic-update-data-file-and-display for a possible bit of help.

Comment: what a great help!! Maybe you can post to the answer section, so I can vote as best answer? And thank you for your precious time

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this:

[Automatic update data file and display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262708/bash-automatic-update-data-file-and-display)

which seems to be a rather good start for what you want to do...